# Proving Muirhead-like inequalities

Tags: inequality

Let $T_{m,n,p}(x,y,z)=\sum_{Sym} x^m y^n z^p$.

For $x,y,z>0$, prove

$2T_{6,3,0}(x,y,z)+T_{3,3,3}(x,y,z)+3T_{4,4,1}(x,y,z)\geq 6T_{5,2,2}(x,y,z)$.

I tried to prove that by using AM-GM inequality, without success.

Is there a general way to prove these "Muirhead-like" inequalities?

Comment: By using Muirhead's inequality

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but I'll answer it anyway.

We should prove that:

$$ \sum_{sym}2x^6 y^3 + x^3 y^3 z^3 + 3 x^4 y^4 z^1 - 6 x^5 y^2 z^2 \ge 0$$

If we divide the inequality by $x^3 y^3 z^3$, we get:

$$ \sum_{sym} 2 \frac{x^3}{z^3} + 1 + 3 \frac{x y}{z^2} - 6 \frac{x^2}{y z} \ge 0$$

Apply the following subsitution:

$$\frac{x}{z}=a, \frac{z}{y}=b, \frac{y}{x}=c$$

The inequality becomes:

$$ \sum_{sym} 2 a^3 + 1 + 3 \frac{a}{b} - 6 \frac{a}{c} \ge 0$$

Note that $abc=1$ so we can homogenize the last inequality in the following way:

$$ \sum_{sym} 2 a^3 + abc + 3 \frac{a}{b} abc - 6 \frac{a}{c} abc \ge 0$$

$$ \sum_{sym} 2 a^3 + abc + 3 a^2 c - 6 a^2b \ge 0$$

If we note that:

$$ \sum_{sym}a^2 b \equiv \sum_{sym}a^2 c $$

...the inequality reduces to:

$$ \sum_{sym} 2 a^3 + abc - 3 a^2b \ge 0$$

...or, by using "Muirhead-like" notation:

$$2T_{3, 0, 0} + T_{1, 1, 1} - 3T_{2, 1, 0} \ge 0$$

...which is obvious, because:

$$T_{3, 0, 0} \ge T_{2, 1, 0} \quad (Muirhead)$$

$$T_{3, 0, 0} + T_{1, 1, 1} \ge T_{2, 1, 0} \quad (Schur)$$

Comment: Michael Rozenberg explained the technique here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720342/inequality-involving-cyclic-sums-muirhead-schur-something-else